# List Detective in API Trigger Sends for Transactional

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, triggered-send

We have various trigger sends definitions setup for transactional notifications. The TSD have now gone live and there has couple of errors under the same error code:

> "messageErrorCode":180008,"messageErrorStatus":"Unable to queue
>   Triggered Send request.  There are no valid subscribers."

However I have checked all the attributes, their types and validations seems to be correct.The API requests doesn't even get through the Triggered data extensions or Triggered Send Definitions. The type of email addresses in the API requests are:

```
mail@xxxxxx.com
mail@yyyyyy.com.au
admin@zzzzz.com.au
```

I am guessing the [List Detective](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/list_detective/) in sfmc is filtering out these types of email addresses and it is a concern for business because these are transactional requests and cannot be ignored.

Has anyone been able to bypass/turn off the List Detective or is there a way to pass these requests in API to TSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I have more clarity around List Detective in API triggered sends.

**Key Points:**

- List Detective cannot be accessed via UI in sfmc and cannot be turned off.
- Only Salesforce support can alter the rules around List Detective and that includes which email domain will included/excluded in the process.
- List Detective updates can be applied within the Business Unit level which means making changes to one BU won't effect other.
- List Detective is mainly to ensure that the sender reputation is maintained which is the reason why it is restrictive around spams.

> Note: The Trigger send error code **[180008](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/18999.htm)** doesn't explain
>   about the list detection error.

Comment: Hi @brad, We have the same issue with one of our account. Around 600 emails were skipped from sending and all the subscribers are from different domains. Any idea, how do we get this rules altered, so SFMC will send email to all users? All these users are valid users actually

Comment: Hey @PraveenKumarBandi, you'll need to raise a support ticket and mention the email addresses that are being blocked due to list detective. sfmc support will then update the list detective in the backend to allow those email addresses into the platform. for eg if admin@xxx.com is blocked then you can request sfmc to allow any emails coming as 'admin@' with any type of valid domain.

Comment: Hey @brad, admin@xxx.com/sales@/info@ would allow bulk of the emails, but still, SFMC is excluding many other valid emails in every send.